# Get server time in javascript with specific timezone

Tags: javascript

How to get **current** server time in javascript with Indian standard timezone?

Comment: The first step would be to tell your server to run PHP in these files. Naming them `.js.php` should suffice.

Comment: We can move to .js.php file. So it will give proper response. But don't forget to  respond with proper header else it will be treated as text. You need to respond with content-type: application/json

Answer (score 1):

you simply put a

```
<script>
    var baseJSURI = '<?php echo base_url(); ?>'; 
</script>
```

somewhere on your page, so you can use it elsewhere in external JS.

Comment: That doesn't work if you don't want this variable to be visible everywhere (and thus subject to name collisions)

Comment: if I understood correctly the question, there can be a single baseurl, why should someone experience name collisions about this? if so, simply change the variable name.